# Error in system(cmd, intern = TRUE) : error in running command

Tags: r, macos, twitter, r-taskscheduler

I am running the following codes to create a scheduled scraping of tweets from Twitter using the "taskscheduleR" package on R Studio:

```
a <- file.path("/Users/udayshankar/Desktop/UPElectionsRfiles/upelections.R") 
taskscheduler_create(taskname = "upelection1",rscript = a,schedule = "ONCE",starttime = "22:11",startdate = format(Sys.Date(),"%d/%m/%Y"))
```

In the vector `a` I have created the path to save the scraped Twitter data into the following file `upelections.R` and saved it into my working directory mentioned in the `file.path()` command.

However, after executing the second command, I get the following error:

> Error in system(cmd, intern = TRUE) : error in running command sh:
>   schtasks: command not found

Please help me troubleshoot the above problem. I have even installed the required X11 package as I am running this on Mac OS X Sierra. I also seem to be unable to access the physical library of R on Mac.

Comment: This isn't related to `R`. It seems like your shell doesn't know how to execute `schtasks`, you are probably missing it. I'm not an expert on Mac OS though, so can't really say what to install

Comment: @G Gamba  I tried to remedy this by referring to this [link](https://kmyu.wordpress.com/2011/01/29/binsh-latex-command-not-found-setting-r-path-to-include-tex-binaries-path/). However, I don't understand as to what you mean by "It seems like your shell doesn't know how to execute schtasks". Please clarify if possible. Thank You.

Comment: Open a **shell** console and type `schtasks`

Comment: @GGamba I ran the following on terminal:Udays-MacBook-Pro:~ udayshankar$ schtasks and afterwards got the following output:
-bash: schtasks: command not found.